# How to parse a nested dictionary with Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am passing a dictionary to template in python

```
   users={
        "output": {
                "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget"
        }
    }

    return render_template('user.html', **locals())
```

but i can not parse the output at response page(user.html).

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <p class="important">
      <ul>
      {% for user in users %}
          <li>{{user}}.title</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>

    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

But i don't get expected output `Sample Konfabulator Widget` while i get `output.title`. How  can i get value of `output.title`?

Comment: Why are you passing `locals()` instead of users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`users` is a one-element dictionary, not a list, so a loop doesn't really make sense.

Since you have just one element, get that without a loop

```
<p>{{users['output']['title']}}</p>
```

---

If you did want multiple "users", and had an element like this

```
users={
    "output": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget"
    }, 
    "output2": {
            "title": "foo"
    }
}
```

Then you could have done a loop

```
  {% for key in users %}
      <li>{{key}} : {{users[key]['title']}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
```